# How to build static library from header-only library

Tags: c, build, cmake

I am trying to build static library of project [stb](https://github.com/nothings/stb), so I can link it in another project (not written in C/C++).

I have created CMakeLists.txt file to build it using CMake, however the built static library file is empty.

I am suspecting this is due to fact that the stb seems to be **header-only** library. I tried setting the `LIBRARY_HEADER_ONLY` flag with `target_compile_definitions`, this however did not solve my problem.

How can I build header-only library to static library file (*.a)? Or is it even possible? If not, what are workarounds if any?

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(stb C)

set(MAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -m64)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -m64)

option(STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION "stb_image implementation" ON)

if(STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION)
    add_definitions(-DSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION)
endif()

option(POSITION_INDEPENDENT_LIB "Use position independent code for static library (if applicable)" ON)
set(SOURCE_FILES stb_image.h stb_truetype.h stb_dxt.h)

add_library(stb_static STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_compile_definitions(stb_static PUBLIC LIBRARY_HEADER_ONLY)
set_target_properties(stb_static PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
set_target_properties(stb_static PROPERTIES
        OUTPUT_NAME stb
        POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ${POSITION_INDEPENDENT_LIB})
```

Comment: Static libraries are really nothing more than archives of object files. If you don't have any object files then you really can't create a static library. If you want to use a header-only C or C++ library together with some non-C or -C++ code, you need to write your own wrapper functions that then can be compiled into object files and used for the static library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The library does have implementation using normal C functions https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h#L469 if the proper #define is present. Therefore I believe that there should be some output from the file, am I wrong? If I split the header file to two (.h and .c) file with header a implementation, would it help?

Comment: @MatejKormuth: At the beginning of the given header, there is a description how to make an implementation. You need to create a `.c` file which has lines    `#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` and `#include "stb_image.h"`. With that source file the library becomes no header only, so all usual mechanisms will work.

Comment: @Tsyvarev so the `add_definitions(-DSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION)` command is not enough?

Comment: Aside from `add_definitions` you need to explain CMake that given headers should be compiled as a sources. Even in this case, not all CMake generators accept libraries without any source file with known extension. Much simpler is to add a source file with proper `#include`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an object files and build a static library from the *header-only library* the extra `.c` file must exists. This is because `.c` files are the ones which contains instructions and code.

Different toolchains may interpret `.h` file differently so the easy and portable way to create the implementation is to create a new `.c` file.

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_DXT_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_TRUETYPE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "stb_image.h"
#include "stb_dxt.h"
#include "stb_truetype.h"
```

Including the header files (`stb_image.h`) and defining the requried macros (`STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION`) in the `.c` file is the solution to get object files and static library (with proper content) out of the build.