# cmake: compile header-only library into a STATIC library

Tags: c++, cmake, header-only

I'm using `VulkanMemoryAllocation`, which is a header only library. I want to compile it into a static library using cmake, but I end up with an empty - 8 bytes sized - library file, and a lot of undefined symbols when linking.

Here is the relevant part of the `CMakeList.txt`

```
# The header with the implementation
add_library(VulkanMemoryAllocator STATIC VulkanMemoryAllocator-Hpp/vk_mem_alloc.h)
# The include path for a wrapper which uses above mentionned header
target_include_directories(VulkanMemoryAllocator PUBLIC VulkanMemoryAllocator-Hpp/)
# enable the actual implementation
target_compile_options(VulkanMemoryAllocator PRIVATE VMA_IMPLEMENTATION)
# consider this file as a C++ file
set_target_properties(VulkanMemoryAllocator PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

EDIT : I want to do the equivalent of this :

```sh
clang++ -c -DVMA_IMPLEMENTATION -x c++ -o vk_mem_alloc.o  ../lib/VulkanMemoryAllocator-Hpp/vk_mem_alloc.h && ar rc libvma.a vk_mem_alloc.o
```

but using CMake

Comment: A static library is an indexed archive of object files. A header only library has no.c* files, thus has no object files compiled from .c* files, thus the static library is 8 bytes, an empty archive.

Comment: CMakeList.txt above does not invoke the linker. You got the errors somewhere you did not show.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build static library from header-only library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927351/how-to-build-static-library-from-header-only-library)

Comment: I don't have any error in CMake log.

I know that a header-only does not have any .c file. What I want to do, is to compile the library implementation (in the header file) into an object file.

Comment: `clang++ -c -DVMA_IMPLEMENTATION -x c++ -o vk_mem_alloc.o  ./VulkanMemoryAllocator-Hpp/vk_mem_alloc.h` 
I want to do that, but using cmake

Comment: A header-only library typically has no compilable code, that's the reason it is header-only to begin with. Binary code is generated only when the library is actually used.

Comment: @fabian yes, but I would prefer a solution without having to create an extra source file.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Some header-only library are separating declaration from implementation (the `#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION` in my example) Those headers can be compiled into a static library. I know how to do it by hand, I just don't know how to do it with CMake.

Comment: `Some header-only library are separating declaration from implementation (the #define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION` That's not `compile_option`, but `target_compile_definitions`

Comment: You may be able to achieve something like this by setting the `LANGUAGE` and `HEADER_FILE_ONLY` source file properties; according to the docs you'll need cmake 3.20 though. Still sceptical that this will yield the desired results, unless this is a possibility described in the header only lib's documentation. I'm not familiar with the lib so I cannot tell.

Comment: 5 min google search: https://github.com/usnistgov/hevx/blob/master/third_party/VulkanMemoryAllocator.cmake

Comment: @KamilCuk well, you're right, my bad xD Changing it doesn't fix the issue, tho. Still having empty library, and missing sybols.

Comment: @KamilCuk And your link is what I'm looking for. Thanks. But I'm still curious about how to do it without having an extra file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VMA_IMPLEMENTATION` is a `compile_definition` not `compile_option`.

You have to set **file** language, in addition to target (I think).

```
set_source_file_properties(
    VulkanMemoryAllocator-Hpp/vk_mem_alloc.h PROPERTIES
    LANGUAGE CXX
)
```

I would just copy the header so that CMake knows it's C++ from extension, it's just simpler.

```
add_custom_command(
    COMMENT 'Copying vk_mem_alloc'
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/vk_mem_alloc.cpp
    DEPENDS VulkanMemoryAllocator-Hpp/vk_mem_alloc.h
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        VulkanMemoryAllocator-Hpp/vk_mem_alloc.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/vk_mem_alloc.cpp
)
add_library(VulkanMemoryAllocator STATIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/vk_mem_alloc.cpp
)
target_include_directories(VulkanMemoryAllocator PUBLIC
    VulkanMemoryAllocator-Hpp
)
target_compile_definitions(VulkanMemoryAllocator PRIVATE
    VMA_IMPLEMENTATION
)
```

Here https://github.com/usnistgov/hevx/blob/master/third_party/VulkanMemoryAllocator.cmake is a similar solution, that creates a C++ file with `#define` and compiles it.

Comment: This is exactly that. Thanks a lot !