# Creating shared library from header only using bazel

Tags: c, shared-libraries, bazel

I am trying create an `.so` file from the Google Differential Privacy framework to import it in another (non-Bazel) project.

The C code is only header files. For the build process they use bazel, so I am trying to stick with that.
I looked at various solutions on StackOverflow. Most of them suggested that this should work:

```
cc_binary(
name= "lib.so",
linkshared=1,
srcs=["header.h","src.c"],
deps=["//framwork:dependency1"],

)
```

However, this does not seem to work in my case. I assume this is due to the fact that I only have .h files for sources.
This is what I got:

```
    cc_binary(
    name= "lib.so",
    linkshared=1,
    srcs=[
       "header1.h",
       "header2.h", 
       ...],
    deps=["//framwork:dependency1", ...],
    
)
```

When compiling with this an .so file is created but there are no symbols or code inside. Therefore, there seems to be a problem with the `cc_binary` rule I used.
Using `linkstatic` in `cc_binary` did not make any difference.

The gcc command executed by Bazel for the rule above looks something like this:

```
gcc -shared -o lib.so -Wl,-S -fuse,ld=gold -Wl,-no-as-needed -Wl,-z,relro,-z,now -Wl,--start-lib logging.pic.o -Wl,--end-lib -Wl,--start-lib hash.pic.o -Wl,--end-lib ... -pthread -pthread -pthread -lpthread -lm -lpthread -lm -lstdc++ -lm
```

Instead of the dots there are a lot more `.pic.o` files which are inserted with `--start-lib` and `--end-lib`. Somehow this command seems wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Looking at the discussions on the Github page of the Bazel project, it seems that creating `.so` files seems to be one of the weak points of Bazel.

Does anyone have an idea what might go wrong here? Is using `cc_shared_library` a solution to this? If yes, how would I use it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what I was trying to do did not really make sense.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927351/how-to-build-static-library-from-header-only-library) post which talks about header-only libraries in CMake.
Since there are no c files, no object files can be created. Therefore, no .so file can be created.

As described in that other post I will try to create a .c file which simply includes all .h files to create a .so file.